# How does GitHub host source code?

Tags: github, distributed, p2p, cloud-hosting

I am researching on how project hosting site works; specially I want to know where they host their project, I am very much interested to know about where GitHub host our projects.

- Do they have a central server?
- Are they using a distributed system?
- Any P2P-like system cloud based?

Any recommended link to know about how GitHub hosting projects. I find that "Git is a distributed system" what is the meaning of it? how it works?

Comment: This not a question, it is a list of questions, and some of them a very broad questions, like "How does a distributed CVS work". I'd recommend you try to find some more info about github at their webpage and read up on distributed versioning systems, and then try to ask more specifik questions here.

Comment: It's cloud-based - see the Rackspace line at the foot of each page - but not P2P. Have a read on Wikipedia, as Kush says, and make a start on [the handbook](http://git-scm.com). Just so you know, discursive questions like this are off-topic - we like programming questions here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Zach Holman](https://github.com/holman)** is a GitHubber.

He gave a talk at **[ScaleConf](http://scaleconf.org/)** and shared some insights about the technical challenges GitHub had to face to host projects in an efficient way. His talk also covers organizational scaling.

The slides of this talk are available on his **[website](http://zachholman.com/talk/scaling-github)**.

Unfortunately, the videos aren't available **[yet](http://twitter.com/scaleconf/status/176999225761087488)**.

His pitch is quite great, too :)

> A month after launching, GitHub hosted one thousand repositories. Three years later, we host over three million. In the same time we've gone from one thousand users to over a million.
>
> This type of scaling presents some interesting technical challenges. I'll dig into our development workflow and how we address concepts like scaling, deployment, code review, and testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not been through Wikipedia page of Git, than you must do [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29).

Also, the [help page](https://help.github.com/) of Git has FAQ which may answer most of your doubts.